Check if all the values of an array is equal to a certain value PHP
I am getting multiple files from upload in a webpage.
I can now check if the files have the right specific extension, I can now also check if the files are in allowable size.
But I also need to verify that there is no error encountered in uploading.
I must check if all the values of $_FILES['file']['error']　is equal to 0 before uploading the files in the database server. How should I check all the value in $_FILES['file']['error'] (which is an array) is equal to 0 before executing my upload code?
Here is my full code:
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','pdf','xlsx','docs','xls','docx','ppt');
    $file_name_checking = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size_checking = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_error_checking = $_FILES['file']['error']; //this is the array to be checked

    $file_name_check_actual_ext = array();

    foreach ($file_name_checking as $extension_files) {

        $extension_actual = explode('.', $extension_files);
        $file_actual_Ext = strtolower(end($extension_actual));
        $file_name_check_actual_ext[] = $file_actual_Ext; 
        
    }

    $file_name_check_ext = '';
    $file_name_check_ext = !array_diff($file_name_check_actual_ext, $allowed);
 
    if($file_name_check_ext === true) {
        if(max($file_size_checking) < 1000000) {
            
            //my upload code
    
            foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
                $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
                $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
                $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$key];
                $file_error = $_FILES['file']['error'][$key];
                $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$key];

                $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
                $file_name_original = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $file_actual_Ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

                $file_name_new = uniqid('',true).".".$file_actual_Ext; 

                $file_destination = '../uploads/'.$file_name_new;

                $result = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $file_destination);

                $query = "INSERT INTO file_storage (
                    file_name,
                    file_size,
                    file_type,
                    file_name_unique,
                    file_ext
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        :file_name, 
                        :file_size, 
                        :file_type,
                        :file_name_unique,
                        :file_ext
                    ) 
                ";

                $stmt=$pdo->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bindParam(":file_name", $file_name_original);
                $stmt->bindParam(":file_size", $file_size);
                $stmt->bindParam(":file_type", $file_type);
                $stmt->bindParam(":file_name_unique", $file_name_new);
                $stmt->bindParam(":file_ext", $file_actual_Ext);

                $stmt->execute();

            }

            if ($result) {
                echo "Files uploaded successfully!";
        
            }
        }

        else {
            echo "File Size is too large!";
        }
    
    }

    else {
        echo "Please check the exension of files";
    }
 
}

I need another if statement before executing my upload code.

What have you've tried? Where are you stuck? Are you receiving any errors?

You set something like $errors = false;, then you loop over $_FILES['file']['error'], and if you encounter an error, you set $errors = true; and leave the loop with break;, and voila, after your loop you now know whether there were any errors, or not. Or it could also be done using array_filter, and checking the number of remaining items (either all of them, or zero of them, depending on whether you filter out entries with errors, or those with no errors.)

You can create a method to verify if your array contains all zeros or not:
<?php

function arrayContainsOnlyZero($array) {
    // Filter the array
    $filteredArray = array_filter($array, function($value) {
        return $value !== 0;
    });
    
    // Return boolean if only zero or not. True means all items are 0
    return empty($filteredArray);
}


// Example usage
$array1 = [0, 0, 0, 0];
$array2 = [0, 1, 0, 2];
$array3 = [0, 0, 0, 0.1];

echo "array1 contains all 0: " . arrayContainsOnlyZero($array1) . "\n";
echo "array2 contains all 0: " . arrayContainsOnlyZero($array2) . "\n";
echo "array3 contains all 0: " . arrayContainsOnlyZero($array3) . "\n";

You can check this PHP sandbox to check
